# Installation errors: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, google-tv

I tried many methods to fix `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` but until now, I can increase my intern storage memory.

The method I tried:

1. Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "Run As" then go to "Run Configurations..." locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, then select your project and go to the "Target" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger) and finally paste "-partition-size 1024" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.
2. Go to Eclipse's Preferences, then Select “Launch” Add “-partition-size 1024” on the “Default emulator option” field, then click “Apply” and use your emulator as usual.
3. Open your .Android directory. Usually in your home directory. Then go to avd and then open the directory that has the name of the avd you would like to change.
4. Now edit the config.ini file and add the following line or modify the following line: `disk.dataPartition.size=1024`

This all  worked for me in Linux.

I used my app to store in external storage by using this:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

but then I received

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE

Comment: s i'm testing it in google tv add on emulator

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem can u help me i got held up for 3 days with this problem

Comment: have you specified size of sdcard?

Comment: @MeghaJoshi-GoogleTVDevRel yes i have specified 1gb size for my sdcard can u help me

Comment: If you email me at lesv (at) google.com I should be able to help you make this issue go away.

Comment: Try to install your application after uninstalling it from the device or emulator that you are using. I had the same issue and solved it by doing this. Hope it helps ...

Comment: @osayilgan i cant install my app in the device it show low space. in the setting my app is not showing bcz it has not install

Answer (score 6):

Error

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE
```

means that your device does not have SD card.

Error

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
```

means that you don't have enough space on device for your app.

You should do next:

1. Write `android:installLocation="auto"` and android itself will care where to install your app - internal or external memory.
2. Be sure that device has enough memory for installing (usually it is more then size of apk).
3. If your app really need much space - read this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html).
4. If you use emulator - setup sd card support: [image]

Comment: i try it but i am getting this error  'emulator-5554': No space left on device
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device
 Launch canceled!

Comment: I've used the sd card support "yes" but till i am getting a same error and in my DDMS i am getting this error transfer error: No space left on device
[2012-07-13 15:02:55 - Device] Error during Sync: No space left on device
[2012-07-13 15:02:55 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8622 for debugger

Comment: can u help me i don't 've any idea what is wrong in my emulator

Comment: Did you try testing on real device?

Comment: no it's google tv app. so i dont 've google tv and i did not test it

Comment: ok.. so first of all send an email lesv@google.com. next, maybe send us your apk and a screencapture so that we can reproduce this. also try..emulator.exe -avd <AvdName> -partition-size 512 -no-snapshot-load

Answer (score 1):

Try with these options, with that configuration I'm able to install one app of 23MB: [image]

Comment: wat is a used off GPU emulation

Comment: Is for accelerate the AVD with the Graphic card instead of the processor to better performance

Comment: i try it.now  it's not even running it showing me blank screen

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling apps that are installed on emulator and not inbuilt. you can also change the size of SD card by editing emulator settings but then it will take time to run your app as that much memory needs to be converted into a mountable partition.

Comment: my total internal memory of google tv emulator is 13mb my app is 10.5mb i can't uninstall all the app is inbuilt

Comment: i have put my sdcard size 2Gb

Answer (score 1):

I have also had a similar problem when I run my app. In my Google TV emulator, it does not show USB storage for external storage. Try to increasing the cache memory and ram size  in a emulator new hardware.

How to increase virtual memory of emulator:

```
\\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

After that, try to install your apk.